# Angular $compile directive keeps repeating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why does this keep repeating? I get a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error in chrome.

```
app.controller('my_cont',function($scope,$compile){
     container.html('<todo></todo>')
     $compile(container)($scope);
})
app.directive('todo',function($compile){
     return{
          template:'<ul><li>Blah</li><li>Blah</li></ul>',
     }
})
```

Comment: What is `container`? Why are you doing DOM manipulation in a controller? Can you update your question with the code that actually shows the error you are getting?

Comment: If container is the element that has the my_cont controller on it, you're going to be recompiling that element and reinstantiating this controller (and resetting the html to todo again and recompiling the whole thing...) which I suspect is the source of the overflow. If you need to do it this way, make a todo element, compile that on its own, then add it to the HTML. Don't add to HTML first.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into that problem before, though not in the same way you have here. Calling $compile on controller initialization like you are here will compile the directive and since the directive initializes a controller and compiles again, you'll have basically infinitely nested controllers. Just put your element directive in your HTML and let Angular compile it for you.

Comment: I am assuming here that the controller for the todo directive is the my_cont controller.

Comment: That is not possible. I need to dynamically insert content and render it. That is what compile is for correct?

Comment: Yes, the compile step compiles directives and turns them into the HTML you specify. Rarely will you need to invoke compile directly, and I've only ever had to do it for recursive HTML, like lists within lists. I'd recommend just having the directive you want to compile in the HTML and show it with ng-show/hide or ng-if letting Angular compile it for you.